# How can I make a simple "AI" for the Matching Card Game (Memory)?

Tags: java

I took some code from a guy around here in Java for the matching card game. The point is that i have an assignment of making it player against the bot.
Basically in the first turn the player picks 2 cards, if they are the same cards he continues otherwise the bots picks two cards.

The problem is that:

1. I dont know how to make a really simple AI so that the bot doesnt just pick 2 random cards.
2. I dont know why but the bot picks only one card. He doesnt pick 2, he picks one.

I'll leave the code here, please help me if you can.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import static javax.swing.UIManager.get;


public class Board extends JFrame{


    public int pairs;
    private List<Card> cards;
    private Card selectedCard;
    private Card c1;
    private Card c2;
    private Timer t;
    boolean pc;

    public Board(int num){

        pairs = num;
        List<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<Card>();
        List<Integer> cardVals = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pairs; i++){
            cardVals.add(i);
            cardVals.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cardVals);

        for (int val : cardVals){
            Card c = new Card();
            c.setId(val);
            c.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    selectedCard = c;
                    doTurn();

                }
            });
            cardsList.add(c);
        }
        this.cards = cardsList;
        //impostazioni timer per rigirare le carte
        t = new Timer(750, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                pc=checkCards();
                if(pc)
                    pcTurn(cardsList,cardVals);
            }
        });

        t.setRepeats(false);

        //impostazioni tavola
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 5));
        for (Card c : cards){
            pane.add(c);
        }
        setTitle("Memory");
    }

    public void doTurn(){ //per girare la carta
        if (c1 == null && c2 == null){
            c1 = selectedCard;
            c1.setText(String.valueOf(c1.getId()));
        }

        if (c1 != null && c1 != selectedCard && c2 == null){
            c2 = selectedCard;
            c2.setText(String.valueOf(c2.getId()));
            t.start();

        }
    }

    public boolean checkCards(){ //per controllare le carte
        boolean flag;
        if (c1.getId() == c2.getId()){//match condition
            c1.setEnabled(false); //disabilita la possibilita di cliccare altre carte mentre due sono girate
            c2.setEnabled(false);
            c1.setMatched(true); //setta il flag positivo se le carte sono uguali
            c2.setMatched(true);
            flag=false;
            if (this.isGameWon()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hai vinto!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        else{
            c1.setText(""); //nasconde il testo
            c2.setText("");
            flag=true;
        }
        c1 = null;
        c2 = null;
        return flag;
    }

    public boolean isGameWon(){ //controllo se la partita è  vinta
        for(Card c: this.cards){
            if (c.getMatched() == false){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public void pcTurn(List<Card> cardsList, List<Integer> cardVals ){
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.nextInt(cardsList.size());
        int y = random.nextInt(cardsList.size());


        if (c1 == null && c2 == null){
            c1 = cardsList.get(x);
            c1.setText(String.valueOf(c1.getId()));
        }

        if (c1 != null && c1 != cardsList.get(x) && c2 == null){
            c2 = cardsList.get(y);
            c2.setText(String.valueOf(c2.getId()));
            t.start();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed your "I took some code from a guy around here in Java for the matching card game." If that is from Stack Overflow, you need to add attribution. Please see [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Please also see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about "homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.".

Comment: When "borrowing" code from others, _caveat emptor_ is the rule of the day (;->)

Comment: Would [Basic Memory Match Game in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85833/basic-memory-match-game-in-java) by any chance be the original source?

Answer (score 4):

You could save every card the bot took in an array with the position of the card. The PC should not choose the same card twice. If he picks up the second card of the pair he should get the position of the first card and pick them both

Comment: It would also be perfectly fair to keep track of every card the _human_ player reveals, as well.

Comment: the problem would be, the bot would be in a insane hardcore mode

Comment: One could add a parameter for how long the bot will remember a revealed card or a liklyhood that the bot remembers a card or a combination of both

Comment: Why not use a bot "difficulty" value between `0` and `1` and take this as a probability that the bot remembers right? `if (difficulty > Math.rnd()) { //pick correct remembered card... }`